# Do Google has some API to retrieve all conversations inside a room in Hangout

Tags: chat, google-hangouts

I am trying to get hold of all conversations that has happened inside a room. I am assuming, as one becomes part of the room, then the same person can see all the past messages that has happened inside the room. Similarly, when a bot is added inside a room, why the bot is not able to get hold of the messages that has been running from past.

Following from the API documentation of Google Chat API, we can only get hold of messages if we have the messageID. So, I have two questions now.

1. Is there any way, we can use any GOOGLE APIs to download conversations inside a room?
2. Is there any way, we can get the messageIDs of the conversations that has happened inside the room?

Thanks
Satya

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you are asking for.